# Override const function google mock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

When trying to mock a function with google test i still get a warning that I miss a "override"

```cpp
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, functionName, (), (const override));
```

The warning I get states

```
xxx.h:31:22: error: 'functionName' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override'
xxx.h:25:17: note: overridden virtual function is here
```

How do you mark a mocked function with `override` and `const` at the same time?

Answer (score 12):

Of course I found it seconds after posting it :/. Separating the keywords by comas is the trick

[from here](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md)

```cpp
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, functionName, (), (const, override));
```